# Web apps with selenium test suit

Tags: selenium, testcase

I am looking for web applications with selenium test cases. Does anybody know any of these web applications?

Comment: are you looking for tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but Selenium is used to create test cases FOR web applications. It is not a feature of web apps.

If you are looking for a simple way to test a web app, you could try the IDE: http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/

This tool is something that beginners could use.

Comment: I am looking for web applications that come with selenium test cases. I would like to use these applications in my evaluation using their pre-written test cases. I could find this one: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.ca/2010/03/selenium-test-suite-for-suteki-shop.html   but I need a few more apps, but could not find any more.

Comment: I don't understand why you are looking for something that has test cases written for you. Test cases need to be written on a case by case basis. Tests that work for one app, won't necessarily work for another. That is the whole point of testing. 
What you need to do is write your own. Selenium IDE has a simple way to do this. All you have to do is open the IDE and click on links write text and so on. Selenium will then translate that into specific test cases.
Even if you were to find a set of test cases for Selenium, there is no guarentee that they will work for your app, or test what you need

Comment: Follow this link and you will see how to write your own test cases for Selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.html#building-test-cases

Comment: I know what your are talking about, but I do not want to evaluate my own web app. I would like to evaluate test cases written for a number of real-web applications (test cases written by those web app's developers). My research is focused on evaluating test cases through mutation testing. If I cannot find enough number of such apps I will write my own test cases for those web applications. But the better way is not to do so and use their pre-written test cases.

Comment: Then I would suggest you Google "Sample test cases" or something similar to that. You would be surprised what you can find on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a page that can give a demo of Selenium tests in action I am not aware of one. The best is to either, try Selenium IDE (as Blaine has suggested +1), or, if you have some coding experience you could try [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html) (also referred to as Selenium 2) which is easy to code and allows for a bit more control when writing tests.

A simple search will also provide you with many Selenium tutorials as it is a fairly popular testing package.